# Python 3.9 code, to get Pandas dataframe column to reference earlier row value in same column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. The 'Flag' column captures whenever the 'Close_Delta' column value changes polarity. I want to add a column whose value is the cumulative sum of the 'Close_Delta' column, but the summing starts afresh every time there is a True value in the 'Flag' column. So the successful result using the dataframe below would be:

```
'Close_Delta'  'Flag'   'Cumulative_Sum'
      1          T          0
     -2          T          0
     -3          F         -3
     -1          F         -4
      2          T          0
      1          F          1
      3          F          4
     -1          T          0
      2          T          0
      4          F          4
     -2          T          0
     -1          F         -1
```

This is easy to do in Excel, not so easy in Pandas dataframes?

I came up with the following code but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Close_Delta': [1, -2, -3, -1, 2, 1, 3, -1, 2, 4, -2, -1],
    'Flag':        [T,  T,  F,  F, T, F, F,  T, T, F,  T,  F]
})

# Create a helper column 'Temp' to identify consecutive F values in 'Flag'
df['Temp'] = (df['Flag'] != df['Flag'].shift(1))

# Calculate cumulative sum only for rows with 'F' in 'Flag'
df['Cumulative_Sum'] = df.groupby('Temp')['Close_Delta'].cumsum()

# Drop the helper column 'Group'
df = df.drop(columns=['Temp'])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific, and elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

with a new Temp helper columns, the dataframe can be splitted to the correct group, and because the row with True value need to be filled with 0, a small UDF is used.

```
import pandas as pd

print("pandas version:", pd.__version__)
T = True
F = False
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Close_Delta": [1, -2, -3, -1, 2, 1, 3, -1, 2, 4, -2, -1],
        "Flag": [T, T, F, F, T, F, F, T, T, F, T, F],
    }
)

# Create a helper column identify consecutive F values in 'Flag'
df["helper"] = df["Flag"].cumsum()
cond = df["Flag"] == False
df.loc[cond, "helper"] = df.loc[cond, "helper"] + 1


def udf_cumulative_sum(x):
    x["Cumulative_Sum"] = x["Close_Delta"].cumsum()
    x.loc[x["Flag"] == True, "Cumulative_Sum"] = 0
    return x


df = df.groupby("helper", group_keys=False).apply(udf_cumulative_sum)

# remove helper
df = df.drop("helper", axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output

```
pandas version: 1.5.3
    Close_Delta   Flag  Cumulative_Sum
0             1   True               0
1            -2   True               0
2            -3  False              -3
3            -1  False              -4
4             2   True               0
5             1  False               1
6             3  False               4
7            -1   True               0
8             2   True               0
9             4  False               4
10           -2   True               0
11           -1  False              -1
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks so much for your prompt reply and solution